# Is product price required for schema.org markup?

Tags: e-commerce, schema.org, google-search-console

One of my client's websites doesn't show prices on their website, they simply have a "Request for Quote" button.

Now in Google Webmaster Tools I'm getting 100s of errors stating the price is missing.

If I'm reading it correctly, on schema.org/Offer it states that Text or Number is accepted.

Can I have "Call for Quote" for my schema price?

Answer (score 3):

The [`price` property](http://schema.org/price) is not required by Schema.org; they don’t require any properties at all, everything is optional.

But Google Search may require certain properties for displaying their Rich Snippets. If you don’t provide these properties, it’s likely that Google won’t show a Rich Snippet for your page. Nothing more.

That said, if you don’t show a price, don’t use the `price` property. "Call for Quote" is not a price. While the `price` property expects "Text or Number", this doesn’t mean that you could have any text or any number as value, it still has to be a price.

Comment: True: On "Call for Quote" as price Google's [structured data testing tool](https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool) says `Call for Quote (The property Call for Quote is not a valid price specification. Learn more about http://schema.org/price.)`

Answer (score 1):

Price has always been the mandatory attribute for Product Snippets (schema.org/Product) and it's value can contain only integer value or integer value with currency sign. Preview of Rich Snippets will not be generated if you don't mark up the price attribute correctly and as it's mandatory attribute so webmaster tools will keep on showing errors.